# Find all occurrences of max value in an unsorted list - single pass with constant memory

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, time-complexity

This question was asked to me in an interview. Given an unsorted list of integers if one can find all occurrences of the max value in linear time and constant memory.

I couldn't answer it back then and came across the median of medians algorithm. Still unsure if this algorithm is applicable in this case.

Comment: what if the array consists only one number? You need O(n) space in worst case.

Comment: Go through the list once to find the max & then again to count how many time it appears in the list. Am I missing something?

Comment: @EugenConstantinDinca, I think this is might actually be a _good_ prefiltering question. The questions don't need to be trick questions or really hard to thin out the applicants

Comment: The question title says 'in single pass', the question body says 'in linear time'. Which is it?

Comment: AakashM, agreed about the confusion, but it's easy to come up with a single solution adhering to both `single-pass` and `linear time`.

Comment: @gnibbler: Indeed. It would've filtered me out since there's a one pass solution...

Comment: @AakashM: Sorry for the confusion. The interviewer told me that I can iterate through the unsorted list just once. Hope this clears the "single pass in subject" and "linear time" in the body problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a max value of a set in O(n). Just go through the list and update the max:

```
max = int_array[0]
for i = 1 to int_array.size():
    if int_array[i] > max:
        max = int_array[i]
```

In the next pass, you can call the desired functionality on every such element. E.g. if you want to print out their position, and finally their count:

```
count = 0
for i = 0 to int_array.size():
    if int_array[i] == max:
        print "Index i"
        count += 1
print count
```

You can always determine the count in the first pass, increasing it whenever the current element is equal to max and resetting it to one every time you *change* the current max (e.g. current element is larger than the current max). In the same way, you could remember the positions of the maximums in the first pass. So, integrating it all to one:

```
count = 1
max = int_array[0]
indexes = [0]
for i = 1 to int_array.size():
    if int_array[i] == max:
        count += 1
        indexes.insert(i)
    else if int_array[i] > max:
        count = 1
        indexes = [i]
        max = int_array[i]
print "There are " + count + " elements with maximal value of " + max
print "On positions: "
for int i = 0 to count:
    print indexes[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a single-pass solution which records the positions of all instances of the maximum:

```
set POS //where the maxima are, initially empty
max = A[1]//first element
add 1 to POS

for i = 2 to n
  if A[i] > max
    max = A[i]
    empty POS
    add i to POS
  if A[i] == max
    add i to POS

return POS
```

The memory usage is `O(n + count(max))` which is `O(n)`, because you have to store the positions of all occurrences of the maximum.

Comment: This will work. Thanks reseter for confirming that I was thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-pass solution to find the maximum and record all the list indices at which the maximum value was seen.

It uses `O(n)` memory if you want to record the list indices. If you only want to count how many times the largest value occurs, replace the lists with counters and you have `O(1)` memory.*

```
numbers = [ ... list of numbers ... ]
largest_seen = - Infinity
positions_seen_at = [ empty list ]

for ( i = 0; i < len(numbers); i++ ):
    if numbers[i] > largest_seen:
        largest_seen = numbers[i]
        positions_seen_at = [ empty list ]

    if numbers[i] == largest_seen:
        positions_seen_at.append(i)
```

*Assuming "reasonable" sized inputs. If the size of the input list is very very large, you might need an arbitrarily long integer to hold the counter. That would be `O(log n)` memory.

Comment: Good point about the O(log n) memory. You could use a arbitrarily large constant number of bytes to store the counter, eg if it can count to the number of particles in the universe you should be fairly safe.

Comment: @gnibbler: How large a number is that, exactly? And will it fit in a 1024-bit integer?

Comment: Most estimates are apparently up to 10**82, so that would give a safety margin of ~200 orders of magnitude :)

Answer (score 1):

Maximum is much easier than median

In Python, if the list of numbers is L, it is as simple as this

```
L.count(max(L))
```

L.count is O(n)
max(L) is also O(n)

This simple solution does look at each element twice, but the algorithm is still O(n) overall

Comment: The question is language independent, so a Phyton function does not explain _the procedure_ of doing what the interview question is asking for. But cheers for "maximum is easier then median" -- everybody just forgot to even mention that part :)

Comment: @penelope, The question as asked here seems to be merely asking whether it is possible. This answer does two passes - single pass was only mentioned in the title which I didn't notice. Single pass is easy enough

Comment: I was not referring to the single/double pass thing. Just, in my opinion, telling somebody "yes, it can be done" without actually explaining how, holds much less worth than accompanying the "yes" with an explanation / references (where applicable).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for such detailed answers. After a bit of thinking I think I have a solution which gives you the max and all occurrences of the max item in a single pass in an unsorted list. Alas!! I could have come up with it a couple of days back :) but better late than never...

Here is the java code snippet I wrote:

```
public int getNumberOfOccurrencesOfMax(List<Integer> inputList){ 

if(this.inputList.size() == 0) 
     return 0;
Integer max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, max_occurances = 0;

for(int i=0; i < inputList.size(); i++){
        if(max < this.inputList.get(i)){
            max = this.inputList.get(i);
            max_occurances = 1;
        }
        else if(max > this.inputList.get(i)){
            max_occurances = (max_occurances > 0) ? max_occurances : 1; 
        }
        else{
            max_occurances += 1;
        }
    }
return max_occurances;
} // END_OF_METHOD
```

I tried the code with an example list of (1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5).

Feel free to suggest any improvement over my implementation.

Best,

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work too:

O(n) algorithm

```
i = 0
highestStart = 0
size = array.size
for i < size -1 
     if array[i] > array[i+1]
          x = array[i]
          delete array[i] //remove higher value
          array[array.size] = x  // push higher value to the end
          highestStart = i
      else if array[i] < array[i+1]
          highestStart = i+1
     end if
  end if
  i = i+1
end for
return subarray[highestStart, array.size -1]

1*,5*,4 ,7 ,9 ,4 ,9   :0,1
1 ,5*,4*,7 ,9 ,4 ,9   :1,2
1 ,4 ,7*,9*,4 ,9 ,5   :2,3
1 ,4 ,7 ,9*,4*,9 ,5   :3,4
1 ,4 ,7 ,4 ,9*,5*,9   :4,5
1 ,4 ,7 ,4 ,5 ,9*,9*  :5,6
```

Comment: I think the deletion of an element in an array is very slow when implemented in any language, and you potentially have one of those in every iteration. Alternatively, if you use linked lists to store the numbers, then deletion and insertion are quite easy, but since it does not bring any complexity improvements, I would just call that an unnecessary complication.